# Creating First Project, Do I Use Separate Activities for Each Screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

So I've been working on an app for a few days now and just got Android Studio and imported my project, and it tells me "Default Activity not found". I was making each screen with a separate layout and just using Visible and Gone. Should I have been making new activities? If so, is there an easy way to move each layout to a new activity?

Also, if that is the case can you please explain the difference? I just started University for my Bachelor of Computer Science and have been self-teaching Java and C++ and would love to learn whatever I can. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An activity represents a user story (or a flow). If in your application some action leads to a completely different user flow you should create a new activity for it.
As an example if you have are showing a list of items in 1 activity and each list item also has a details page you should ideally create a different activity for it.

Also you can invoke the same activity from different places thus minimising complexity.

In your case you simply need to define new activities and in the onCreate method of each activity set the respective layouts.